# make the css grid cell take up all the remaining space

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a 3 cells grid.

I want cells 1 and 3 to be the same size and cell 2 to fill all the remaining space.

like this:

```
| abcdefghi | ...........abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz........... | ......abc |
```

I tried `grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr` Unfortunately, `auto` uses as little space as possible and I get something like this:

```
| abcdefghi........... | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | .................abc |
```

Is there a way to do this with css-grid?

```css
.foo {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr; 
  
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.foo div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.foo div:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

.foo div:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='foo'>
  <div>abcdefghi</div>
  <div>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
  <div>abc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no way for the first column to know the size of the third, or vice versa. So those columns can't be the same size unless you define the length. https://jsfiddle.net/1g79458p/

Comment: when i use `grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr` cells 1 & 3 have the same size, so it is possible

Comment: I meant in the context of your desired layout. Yes, you can make columns 1 & 3 the same size, but you don't get the layout you want.

Comment: As I see it, you have two options. Either you set a fixed width for columns 1 and 3, or you can use the following get column 2 to grow but columns 1 and 3 will be different sizes. `grid-template-columns: max-content auto max-content;`